# python syntax that divides multiple returned values into separate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am using a google search method to attain the top 5 links for five animals and I want to make a data frame for each animal (each animal has five links). The data frame for one animal (panda) needs to essentially look like the one shown below. There are five rows, col 1 is panda, col 2 is ONE link

[image]

But Right now it looks like this (as shown below) just one row, col 1 panda, col 2 all five links in one cell

[image]

How do I make it so that my code will make a data frame that separates the five links into their cell in a separate row like in image #1? Is there a python syntax for that? (I would like to run the code through a for loop but I get an AttributeError. The code should work for a list of animals creating separate dataframes for each one, Panda is just an example of what one of an animal dataframe should look like).

Comment: explode(), perhaps - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Comment: use split(',') and explode to get them on separate rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Create new DF for each Animal

You can split and explode the dataframe. Then use groupby to create a separate dataframe for each Animal. Here's how to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal':['Panda', 'Tiger','Monkey'],
                   'Link':['abcde.com, fghijk.com, lmnopq.com, rstuvw.com, xyz.com',
                           'adobe.com, facebook.com, linkedin.com, google.com, citi.com',
                           'amazon.com, bbc.com, cnn.com, fox.com, abc.com'],})

#Convert all the data into multiple rows
df = (df.set_index(['Animal'])
   .apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',').explode())
   .reset_index()) 

#create a dictionary of pandas dataframe for each animal
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Animal')))

#store the dataframes into a list
dfx = []

#Iterate through each key in the dictonary, and append to list
for k in d:
    dfx.append(d[k])

#example
print (type(dfx[1])) #will result in <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print (dfx[0]) #will print dataframe for Animal = 'Monkey'

print (dfx[1]) #will print dataframe for Animal = 'Panda'

print (dfx[2]) #will print dataframe for Animal = 'Tiger'
```

The output of this will be:

type of each DataFrame in the list `dfx` is:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

`dfx[0]` will give you:

```
    Animal        Link
10  Monkey  amazon.com
11  Monkey     bbc.com
12  Monkey     cnn.com
13  Monkey     fox.com
14  Monkey     abc.com
```

`dfx[1]` will give you:

```
  Animal         Link
0  Panda    abcde.com
1  Panda   fghijk.com
2  Panda   lmnopq.com
3  Panda   rstuvw.com
4  Panda      xyz.com
```

`dfx[2]` will give you:

```
  Animal           Link
5  Tiger      adobe.com
6  Tiger   facebook.com
7  Tiger   linkedin.com
8  Tiger     google.com
9  Tiger       citi.com
```

Note that groupby will use alphabetic order so Monkey, then Panda, then Tiger

## Prev solution to split and explode

Here's how I will do it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal':['Panda'],
                   'Link':['abcde.com, fghijk.com, lmnopq.com, rstuvw.com, xyz.com']})
print (df)
df = (df.set_index(['Animal'])
   .apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',').explode())
   .reset_index()) 
print (df)
```

Original DataFrame:

```
  Animal                                                    Link
0  Panda  abcde.com, fghijk.com, lmnopq.com, rstuvw.com, xyz.com
```

Updated DataFrame:

```
  Animal         Link
0  Panda    abcde.com
1  Panda   fghijk.com
2  Panda   lmnopq.com
3  Panda   rstuvw.com
4  Panda      xyz.com
```

I did not change any code. Here's the solution with multiple records.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal':['Panda', 'Tiger','Monkey'],
                   'Link':['abcde.com, fghijk.com, lmnopq.com, rstuvw.com, xyz.com',
                           'adobe.com, facebook.com, linkedin.com, google.com, citi.com',
                           'amazon.com, bbc.com, cnn.com, fox.com, abc.com'],})
print (df)
df = (df.set_index(['Animal'])
   .apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',').explode())
   .reset_index()) 
print (df)
```

Before:

```
Animal                                                            Link
0   Panda        abcde.com, fghijk.com, lmnopq.com, rstuvw.com,xyz.com
1   Tiger  adobe.com, facebook.com, linkedin.com, google.com, citi.com
2  Monkey               amazon.com, bbc.com, cnn.com, fox.com, abc.com
```

After:

```
    Animal           Link
0    Panda      abcde.com
1    Panda     fghijk.com
2    Panda     lmnopq.com
3    Panda     rstuvw.com
4    Panda        xyz.com
5    Tiger      adobe.com
6    Tiger   facebook.com
7    Tiger   linkedin.com
8    Tiger     google.com
9    Tiger       citi.com
10  Monkey     amazon.com
11  Monkey        bbc.com
12  Monkey        cnn.com
13  Monkey        fox.com
14  Monkey        abc.com
```

Comment: How would I use this when iterating through multiple animals though? Like I want to do the same for a list of animals, not just a panda. I tried iterating it through a for loop but I got an AttributeError explaining how list(what my list is called- contains different animals) does not attribute to split. Thank you again your code helped me a lot.

Comment: @ChristinaChang, See my answer with more records. I didn't change any code. It works as is. Share your data so we can see what variation you have in your dataset

Comment: Ohhh okay makes sense. Rather, I have my data inside an excel sheet in which I export out into a list since there are 30+ animal rows. Here is my data:                                                                                         df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Chris\Downloads\AnimalList.xlsx')
list = [ ]
for index in df.iterrows():
    list.append(index)                                                                                                                   In this case, how would I insert every animal into the record? Since it isn't just a few.

Comment: Can you please share a few records from your excel so I can see what it looks like. Or share a google sheets link with the data. You should try and avoid using iterrows() whenever possible. This one does not need an iterrows() unless your data is very complicated.

Comment: Sure, take a look above at my post I just added it at the bottom "Image of Spreadsheet." What I essentially want to do is take each animal name, run a google search and pull the top 5 links of websites that contain the animal's name, and make a separate data frame for each animal containing the links (the part I need help with), and write it/save it off as a csv file. I'll do this for every animal - so basically 10 animals = 10 data frames = 10 csv files.

Comment: You can iterate through each row in the dataframe and create a separate dataframe for that.

Comment: See if the solution I have provided helps you. If you need another solution, I can provide you. This may be the best way to address the need for separate dataframes for each animal.

Answer (score 0):

If each Link cell contains one string separated by commas, you can do it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal':['Panda'], 'Link':['google.com, apple.com, amazon.com']})
print(f'Before:\n{df}\n')

df['Link'] = df['Link'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
df = df.explode('Link')
print(f'After:\n{df}')


#output:
Before:
  Animal                               Link
0  Panda  google.com, apple.com, amazon.com

After:
  Animal         Link
0  Panda   google.com
0  Panda    apple.com
0  Panda   amazon.com
```

Alternatively, if each cell contains a list of links, you can eliminate the split statement above and just explode.

Comment: may need to `reset_index()`.

Comment: How would I use this when iterating through multiple animals though? Like I want to do the same for a list of animals, not just a panda. I tried iterating it through a for loop but I got an AttributeError explaining how list(what my list is called- contains different animals) does not attribute to split. Thank you again your code helped me a lot.

Comment: You wouldn't iterate.  Your dataframe would presumably have one animal per row in the Animal column and one string of links in Link column.  The code above would explode all the links for all the animals.